# Salvar multiplas fotos no Banco SQL no mesmo ID

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, asp.net, imagem

estou tendo dificuldade em salvar varias fotos em um unico id
esse é o cs da pagina que faz o cadastro

```
protected void btnSalvarImovel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Imovel(IdCidade,IdLocal,Idtipo,IdOperacao,Titulo,Obs,QntQuarto,Valor,Foto)" +
            "values(@IdCidade,@IdLocal,@Idtipo,@IdOperacao,@Titulo,@Obs,@QntQuarto,@Valor,@Foto)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdCidade", ddlCidade.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdLocal", ddlLocalizacao.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdTipo", ddlTipoImovel.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdOperacao", ddlOperacao.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", txtTitulo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Obs", txtObservacao.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QntQuarto", txtQtdQuartos.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor", txtValor.Text);
                foreach (var file in fuFotos.PostedFiles)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Imovel/" + filename));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", file);

                }
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception("Erro ao salvar a Imóvel, atualize a página e tente novamente, se persistir o erro, contate o suporte" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

no caso o FOREACH seria o loop para armazenar varias fotos

e da o seguinte erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria que ficasse -+ assim no banco
o que eu posso fazer? alguma dica?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Existem alguns problemas com seu código, entre eles:

1 - `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Foto", file);` você está adicionando vários parâmetros "Foto" pois está dentro do for;
2 - Você está jogando no parametro foto o arquivo em si e não seu caminho no servidor _C:/.../..._;

Da uma olhada nisso e depois me fala aqui se conseguiu algum progresso.

Comment: Você está tentando armazenar o arquivo da foto no banco? Se for isso, é uma ideia ruim. Pelo que eu entendi um imóvel possui várias fotos, certo? Pense melhor na maneira como vocês está fazendo, pois você tem um relacionamento 1:N (seria interessante uma tabela). Porém você pode armazenar os paths das fotos usando um carácter para separar os path e quando recurerar do banco usar o Split para obter a lista de path das fotos....

Comment: boa noite... consegui fazer... muito ong a todos ... mas poderia me ajudar em um outro problema ou tenho que fazer outro post? @JcSaint?

Comment: @AndréFelipeJardimFirmo como se trata de outro problema é melhor que você abra uma nova pergunta, assim outros aps podem ser ajudados caso tenham o mesmo problema... :)